# Unable to get multiple ng-apps to show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cesiumjs

I am trying to display mutiple ng-apps on the same page but not all of them will show at the same time. For the life of me I cant figure out why only one will display when I set the ng-app

**index.html**

```
<!--timestamp-->
<div class="timeStamp" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='TimeCtrl'>
        <p>{{ clock | date:'MM-dd-yyyy  HH:mm:ss'}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!--cesium-->
<div class="cesium" ng-app="ngCesium" ng-controller="appCtrl as appCtrl">
    <div cesium-directive="" id="cesium" class="cesiumContainer"></div>
</div>

<!--legend items -->
<div ng-app="" class="categoryBox" data-ng-init="planes=['Commercial Planes','Private Planes']">
    Legend
    <li data-ng-repeat="x in planes" ng-style="{ background: x == 'Commercial Planes' ? 'red' : 'blue' }">
        {{x}}
    </li>

</div>
```

**timeAnguar.js**

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    var tick = function() {
        $scope.clock = Date.now();
    }
    tick();
    $interval(tick, 1000);
});
```

**cesium.js**

```
"use strict";

angular.module('ngCesium', [])

    .directive('cesiumDirective', function ($interval) {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            controllerAs: "cesiumCtrl",
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {

            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

                ctrl.cesium = new Cesium.Viewer(element[0], {
                    baseLayerPicker: false,
                    fullscreenButton: true,
                    homeButton: false,
                    sceneModePicker: false,
                    selectionIndicator: false,
                    timeline: false,
                    animation: false,
                    geocoder: false,
                    infoBox: false
                });
                var longitudeCol = -76.795292;
                var latitudeCol = 39.176810;

                var longitudeSan = -117.231192;
                var latitudeSan = 33.139597;


                ctrl.cesium.camera.flyTo({
                    destination: new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitudeSan, latitudeSan)
                });
                ctrl.cesium.entities.add({
                    position: new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitudeCol, latitudeCol),
                    point: {
                        pixelSize: 5,
                        color: Cesium.Color.GREEN,
                        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
                        outlineWidth: 2
                    },
                    label: {
                        text: 'Leidos Columbia',
                        font: '12pt monospace',
                        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL_AND_OUTLINE,
                        outlineWidth: 2,
                        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM,
                        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -9)
                    }
                });

                ctrl.cesium.entities.add({
                    position: new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitudeSan, latitudeSan),
                    point: {
                        pixelSize: 5,
                        color: Cesium.Color.GREEN,
                        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
                        outlineWidth: 2
                    },
                    label: {
                        text: 'Leidos San Diego',
                        font: '12pt monospace',
                        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL_AND_OUTLINE,
                        outlineWidth: 2,
                        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM,
                        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -9)
                    }
                });
                ctrl.cesium.entities.add({
                    polyline: {
                        positions: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([longitudeCol, latitudeCol,
                            longitudeSan, latitudeSan]),
                        width: 1,
                        material: Cesium.Color.PURPLE
                    }

                })
            }
        };

    })

    .controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }]);
```

Comment: "Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document ... ... To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using `angular.bootstrap` instead" [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

Comment: is their a solution or workaround to fixing this? Use my example to show please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. The ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the  or  tags.
>
> ***Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document.*** The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using [`angular.bootstrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) instead. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.

Straight from the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

Instead of modules, use separate controllers. Those controllers can then be placed on different sections of your HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body>
    <div class="section_one" ng-controller="myAppController">
      myApp stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="section_one" ng-controller="ngCesiumController">
      Cesium stuff here
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the response and I am attempting to mock this but I am still not understanding it.

Comment: Let's put it this way: You have 2 modules: `ngCesium` and `myApp`. In each of the modules, you'll have a bunch of controllers, directives, services, that kind of stuff. Both modules share the _same_ html page. How is each module to know what part of the HTML it can act on, and what it can't? A `{{variable}}` will be watched by both modules. That results in conflict... Basically, what you're trying to do doesn't work.

Comment: now that makes way more sense. What would your suggestion be for my example. What is the best way to resolve these conflicts?

Comment: Instead of modules, use separate controllers. Those controllers can then be placed on different sections of your HTML

Comment: lets use the cesium and timeAngular as an example how could I combine them into one?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either of those.

Comment: how would I combine the two above into one module with separate controllers

Comment: You can just add your `cesiumDirective` to the `myApp` module, instead of the `ngCesium` module. Your cesium controller is empty, so I see no point in keeping it.

Comment: So, @user2402107, does this answer your question?